# How to pass called WebDriver driver from @BeforeMethod to @Test in TestNG Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have this class SignIn:

```
package automationFramework;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObject.devSplashScreenPage;
import utility.BrowserType;
import utility.Constant;
import appModule.SignIn_Action;

public class SignIn {

    public WebDriver driver;



@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("browser")
public void SetUp(String browser) {

    BrowserType.Execute(driver, browser);

}

@Test
public  void signIn() {

    // Call Sign In function
    SignIn_Action.Execute(driver, Constant.StudentUsername, Constant.StudentPassword);    
 }  

@AfterMethod
public void Teardown() {
      driver.quit();

} 

  }
```

Where I am calling this code below which chooses the specific browser by the parameter that is passed. It works perfectly fine, it picks up the right browser and executes.

```
package utility;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class BrowserType {



    @Test
    public static void Execute(WebDriver driver, String browser) {

         // Set Browsers
         if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         }

         else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) { 

         {System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");}
          driver = new ChromeDriver();        
          }

         else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) { 

              {System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");}
              driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
              {DesiredCapabilities iecapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
              iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);}
              }

          // Implicit Wait and Maximize browser
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.manage().window().maximize();

          // Navigate to URL
          driver.get(Constant.URL);


    } 

    }
```

So everything executes perfectly fine in @BeforeMethod, the issue I have is the test stops because the driver doesn't pass from @BeforeMethod to @Test.

How can I get the driver that is initiated by running BrowserType.class into the @Test Sign_in.class. I guess how can i return the driver properly from browsertype and call it in Sign_in @Test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

BrowserType.java:

```
package utility;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class BrowserType {

    @Test
    public static WebDriver Execute(String browser) {

         // Set Browsers
         WebDriver driver = null;
         if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         }

         else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) { 

         {System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");}
          driver = new ChromeDriver();        
          }

         else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) { 

              {System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");}
              driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
              {DesiredCapabilities iecapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
              iecapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);}
              }

          // Implicit Wait and Maximize browser
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.manage().window().maximize();

          // Navigate to URL
          driver.get(Constant.URL);

          return driver;

    }
```

SignIn.java class:

```
package automationFramework;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import pageObject.devSplashScreenPage;
    import utility.BrowserType;
    import utility.Constant;
    import appModule.SignIn_Action;

    public class SignIn {

    public WebDriver driver;



    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void SetUp(String browser) {

        driver = BrowserType.Execute(browser);

    }

    @Test
    public  void signIn() {

        // Call Sign In function
        SignIn_Action.Execute(driver, Constant.StudentUsername, Constant.StudentPassword);    
     }  

    @AfterMethod
    public void Teardown() {
          driver.quit();

    } 

      }
```

Comment: Your .Execute method should not be a Test annotated method.  Instead, your BrowserType class should be an abstract class that the SignIn class extends.   Then, you can have your SetUp method inside the BrowserType class instead of having it in your SignIn test class.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Don't really understand it. Thanks

Comment: It's just basic polymorphism:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 0):

The way your doing things can be greatly improved.

```
public class BrowserTest extends TestBase{
    @Test(dataProvider="test1")
    public static void execute(WebDriverHelper helper, String browser) {
         // Set Browsers
         driver.get(url);
```

Just pass the driver object (coming from the DataProvider).   I assume your generating the driver instance within the DataProvider method since your test method is already parameterized and takes the driver.

```
public class TestBase {
    private WebDriver driver;
    ...
    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void setUp(Object[] params) {
        driver = (WebDriverHelper)params.get(1);
        browserName = (String)params.get(2);
        this.setTestName( params.get(0) + "-" + browserName;
        driver.navigateTo(startUrl);    
    }
```

This code I show above wont compile but what I am trying to convey here is that you need to use the optional TestNG arg to the `@BeforeMethod` method, which is `Object[]` , and it gives you access to objects passed to test methods, BEFORE the test method is called, such as getting access to a "driver helper" created in the DataProvider factory, and then doing some Capabilities setup on that before the test is ran.

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] { 
   { "Cedric", new WebDriverHelper(), "firefox" },
   { "Anne", new WebDriverHelper(), "chrome"}
 }; 
}
```

Comment: actually i am not using @Dataproviders at all.

Comment: I understand.  I was just trying to suggest that using the DataProvider makes multi-threaded handling of driver instances a lot easier (if your not using Spring).

Comment: yeah i have to look into data provider in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your `Execute` function return the driver:

```
public static WebDriver Execute(String browser) {
    ...
    return driver;
}
```

In your test:

```
public void SetUp(String browser) {
    driver = BrowserType.Execute(browser);
}
```

Comment: I tried returning the driver before, but it doesn't work. It gives me an error "void methods cannot return a value"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestSuiteDriver {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Kimberleyross/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return TestSuiteDriver.driver;
    }
}
```